# Debugging with Kendo UI in Visual Studio?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, kendo-ui

I'm rather new to Kendo but not javascript or jquery. I recently was given a ASP.NET project to track down an issue in and I can debug the MVC controller actions ok, just not the javascript.  Its using the Kendo UI library and none of the client side breakpoints are being hit. Its possible the events arent even attached.

I managed to fire up the chrome developer tools as discussed [here](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/details/screencast-debugging-kendo-ui-applications), but the breakpoint I set is not hit when I debug.  How can I check if the event handler has even been attached?

Comment: Just put a `console.log()` inside the event to see if it's hit or not. Kendo UI is nothing but a javascript/jquery library. You debug it the same way you debug your jquery code.

Comment: As I suspected, the event isnt even getting hit.  Now the problem of finding out why the event isnt firing.  Thanks, this confirms what I suspected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Chrome as your browser, try this.

Somewhere in your script tags, paste this
`//@@sourceURL=YourJavaScriptFile.js`

Once you save the script file, use F12 tools in Chrome to go to Sources tab. Your javascript should be displayed in one of the html pages there. You can then put a breakpoint in Chrome script file and refresh your web page to debug.